# datetimepicker not working when input box was dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a button that dynamically add row. The row includes some input and select box. While I'm using datetimepicker on one of the input box, the cloned input boxes are unable to display datetimepicker, only the first one able.

Below are the snippet, anyone can help?

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format : "YYYY-MM-DD",
      ignoreReadonly: true
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Add row" onClick="addRow('dyn_table')" />
<table class="table" id="dyn_table">
  <tbody><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="dyn_xbPayment big-checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_payment_method">Payment Method</label>
          <select name="dyn_item_code[]" class="dyn_item_code form-control">
            <option disabled="" selected="" value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value="cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
            <option value="tt">TT</option>
            <option value="cc">Credit Card</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9].[0-9]" class="dyn_amount" name="dyn_amount[]" step="0.01">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_reference">Reference Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="dyn_reference form-control" name="dyn_reference[]" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_cheque_date">Cheque Date</label>
          <input type="text" class="dyn_cheque_date form-control datetimepicker" name="dyn_cheque_date[]" >
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use a [delegated event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you must apply again the plugin to that new genereted element

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

  }
  ApplyPicker();
}

function ApplyPicker() {
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    ignoreReadonly: true
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  ApplyPicker();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Add row" onClick="addRow('dyn_table')" />
<table class="table" id="dyn_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="dyn_xbPayment big-checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_payment_method">Payment Method</label>
          <select name="dyn_item_code[]" class="dyn_item_code form-control">
            <option disabled="" selected="" value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value="cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
            <option value="tt">TT</option>
            <option value="cc">Credit Card</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9].[0-9]" class="dyn_amount" name="dyn_amount[]" step="0.01">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_reference">Reference Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="dyn_reference form-control" name="dyn_reference[]">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label for="dyn_cheque_date">Cheque Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="dyn_cheque_date form-control datetimepicker" name="dyn_cheque_date[]">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, can you also look at the styling why the calendar box is out of range?

Comment: @user8913806 for that you must wrap it with a relative position container or also known in bootstrap as any `col-x-size` class, see my edit, If you want everything look the same you should add same classes

Answer (score 0):

Make a small change to your javascript code:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
  }

  setDatepickers();
}

setDatepickers = function() {
   $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format : "YYYY-MM-DD",
      ignoreReadonly: true
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setDatepickers();
})
```

After you insert 'new' html you tell jQuery to load datapicker also for new elements

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format : "YYYY-MM-DD",
    ignoreReadonly: true
  });
  
  addRow = function(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
      var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
      newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
    
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format : "YYYY-MM-DD",
      ignoreReadonly: true
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Add row" onClick="addRow('dyn_table')" />
<table class="table" id="dyn_table">
  <tbody><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="dyn_xbPayment big-checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_payment_method">Payment Method</label>
          <select name="dyn_item_code[]" class="dyn_item_code form-control">
            <option disabled="" selected="" value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value="cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
            <option value="tt">TT</option>
            <option value="cc">Credit Card</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9].[0-9]" class="dyn_amount" name="dyn_amount[]" step="0.01">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_reference">Reference Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="dyn_reference form-control" name="dyn_reference[]" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_cheque_date">Cheque Date</label>
          <input type="text" class="dyn_cheque_date form-control datetimepicker" name="dyn_cheque_date[]" >
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add Date Picker Code in **addRow** function and It will work.

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
  }
  
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format : "YYYY-MM-DD",
      ignoreReadonly: true
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format : "YYYY-MM-DD",
      ignoreReadonly: true
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Add row" onClick="addRow('dyn_table')" />
<table class="table" id="dyn_table">
  <tbody><tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="dyn_xbPayment big-checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_payment_method">Payment Method</label>
          <select name="dyn_item_code[]" class="dyn_item_code form-control">
            <option disabled="" selected="" value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value="cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
            <option value="tt">TT</option>
            <option value="cc">Credit Card</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number" pattern="[0-9].[0-9]" class="dyn_amount" name="dyn_amount[]" step="0.01">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_reference">Reference Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="dyn_reference form-control" name="dyn_reference[]" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dyn_cheque_date">Cheque Date</label>
          <input type="text" class="dyn_cheque_date form-control datetimepicker" name="dyn_cheque_date[]" >
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```